# How can I increase max file upload in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I set in php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
```

Then try .htaccess file

```
php_value  upload_max_filesize  64M
php_value  post_max_size  64M
```

And in wp-config.php `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');` But nothing helps me. The max upload size left 32px;

How can I increase max file upload in Wordpress?

Comment: In a Multisite one can increase the upload filesize in the Network Settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Earlier adding `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');` just after `<?php` on wp-config.php always worked for me. For the latest wordpress version it isn't working. I don't know the actual reason behind it but it still works for my older wordpress sites which I never updated from last year.

Follow these steps for latest Wordpress:

1) Put this at the end of your php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 512M
post_max_size = 512M
max_execution_time = 300
```

2) Restart apache(Setting won't take effect until apache is restarted)

[Tested and working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7iJ1.png).

> I tried both **.htaccess** and and **php.ini on wp-admin** methods as well, They
>   aren't working either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in PHP :

```
ini_set('post_max_size', 100000); // 10Mo
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', 100000);
```

But be careful, with some of server supplier you cannot change this limit...

Comment: I just create php5.ini and put it in the root of my directory, after some time it tooks effect.

Answer (score 0):

I tried different way like attempted to

```
1. change my limit directly on my server
2. through the .htaccess file 
3. wp-config.php
```

but none of these changes worked for me. Then I came across a post somewhere That I summarised in a blog post(find below)

```
All you need to do is 
1. create a php.ini 
2. upload to admin directory
```

here is a link if you want to know more http://ecarobar.com/increase-max-upload-file-size-in-wordpress/