# Wordpress Max File Size

Tags: wordpress, file, size, max

I wanted to upload a couple themes and plugins on my wordpress and found out it hat a max filesize of 2MB. So I googled how to solve and did the following without any effects:

- I changed the php.ini
- I copied the php.ini into the wp-admin folder
- edited the .htacces
- edited the wp-config.php
- dowonloaded a plugin which was able to increase the upload size of the media but not for the themes and plugins.

I'm running an Apache Webserver, PHP and MySQL on a Debian 8 vServer and used the following guide to set up multiple websites on the server:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-wordpress-sites-on-a-single-ubuntu-vps

Pretty frustrated right now so any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Following [this answer here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-can-i-increase-the-upload_max_filesize-in-wordpress) - if you haven't done so, make sure you run

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

after you edit the php.ini file.

This was also answered in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156069/how-can-i-increase-max-file-upload-in-wordpress?rq=1) by [Rajender Joshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1973411/rajender-joshi) and it seems that you need to add this to end of your php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 512M
post_max_size = 512M
max_execution_time = 300
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did other than change the value to 64M instead of 512M. I restarted apache every time