# Wordpress PHP.INI nightmare

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-admin, upload-max-filesize

I tried uploading a theme and i got the error

'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.'

First, I couldn't find a php.ini file, then I sought help and I was told to create it which I did and also edited. Till date, Nothing has changed. Same error. I created the php.ini file in the public_html directory, no luck. In the public_html/wp-admin directory, no luck as well. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Your hosting company's support staff should be able to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I increase max file upload in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156069/how-can-i-increase-max-file-upload-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php.ini is the core configuration of PHP. It's located on the server. You can change `upload_max_filesize` from php.ini files.

#### If you don't have the access of php.ini files then you can create a `.htaccess`file (not needed if already have) in the project directory. Because `.htaccess` the file can overwrite the main php.ini config.

After create .htaccess put the following line in `.htaccess`

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M
```

### Note

If you have cPanel access, many cPanel provide the opportunity to change the upload_max_filesize from cPanel configuration.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuu!!!!! I'll cry. Honestly. I was almost dead. This works! two weeks! two whole weeks!!!!! This is my first question here. I really should come here often.

Comment: you're welcome and I'm happy to know that it is working for you :)